# Is the emitter or the collector the big, bulky part of a PNP bjt?

Tags: transistors, diodes, bjt

When I was looking at about 50 PNP cross section pictures on Google, half of them were PNPs with the large part on the bottom labelled as collector, and the other half appeared to have the large part labelled emitter (although in fact they were a specific species of PNP with a tiny emitter). I am not sure whether the PNP also has its collector as the large part of the body.

It would make sense for the large bulky part to be the opposite of an NPN. That is, it would make sense that the emitter is the large bulky part in a PNP, whereas the large bulky part is the collector in an NPN. In an NPN, the signal (base) to + charge emitter (collector) contact needs to have a large surface area. Following the same reasoning, in a PNP, the signal (base) to + charge emitter (emitter) needs to have a large surface area. Absent a physical diagram, C and E are only defined w.r.t. where the + or - charge is coming in or out. The positive-charge-emitting contact needs to be large in a NPN, so should it be in a PNP. Hence my intuition.

Is there anyone who has who has experience with these transistors that can inform me about this?

Comment: Maye you can visually show a site that is wrong because I've not found any.

Comment: I saw many types of structures, lateral, deep well etc , but all have the collector as the bulk part over  a substrate where the CB junction forms your Miller Capacitance for the reverse biased PN junction. ( i.e. none were wrong) AFAICT

Comment: So at a third glance, the pictures I was looking at which were confusing me were deep well and have a small collector, and TINY emitter, so I was confusion. At least there is further visual corroboration below - albeit that I still don't know the exact reason for any of this.

Comment: BJT circuits mainly operate in their active region hence, the majority of the power dissipated is from within the base/collector region. Given that the base is a tiny layer inside a sandwich, it makes total sense that the collector becomes the heatsink. Emitter current being greater than collector current is a red-herring.

Comment: @Andyaka I suppose the majority of the voltage drop occurs at the base-collector interface. That explanation for a large collector surface area makes sense. Thank you for providing a lucid explanation, and please accept my apology for the comment I left previously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want the collector to be on the bottom to get the heat out. Eg.(2N2907 from [here](https://siliconsupplies.com/media/literature/ss/2N2907A.pdf)):

[image]

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, not challenging, but if more current flows through the emitter than the collector, why wouldn't the emitter be one to move closest to the heatsink? And is the die thick enough that it really matters?

Comment: Great, even regardless of the rationale it's visually clear that the collector is larger than the emitter. Thank you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Only marginally more current flows through the emitter. I'm basing that suggestion on the fact that every power transistor I can recall has the die mounted and collector connected directly to the metal case, tab or metal lead frame.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Clifton Fonstadt's Microelectronics tries to suggest why this is so specifically for phototransistors: "The base-collector junction is made as large as necessary to collect the incident signal, and the emitter-base junction is kept small to block as little of the lower junction as practical"; https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/34219 ; page 231 if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Admittedly, the "explanation" doesn't say much.

Comment: Phototransistors are going to be a special case. Not sure I've ever seen a modern PNP phototransistor in discrete form, though I scraped the black paint off some surplus OC71s back in the day. They were filled with grease but still limited to 50mW or something like that.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, if you're operating the transistor fully switched, the power it uses should be fairly low (so it doesn't matter too much which region gets the best heat sinking). If you're operating the transistor in the linear region (forward active) the collector and emitter currents are nearly equal, but the voltage across the collector region can be much higher than across the base-emitter junction.

Comment: @ThePhoton OK, I see, the result is that the power dissipated in the collector will typically be much greater than in the emitter, not because the current is higher but because the voltage drop is higher. Thanks.